# EffectComposer - Access the image created by the Composer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a question/problem regarding the EffectComposer.

What I'm trying to do:
I try to split up all of the post-processing used in my App between multiple EffectComposers.
I would like to be able to calculate e.g. 5 shaders in *EffectComposer1*, then take the image created by this composer and pass it back into a uniform in e.g. *EffectComposer2*. 
Both the geometry and the texture used in EffectComposer1 are suitable (in terms of their pixel-size) to be used as a uniform in *EffectComposer2*.

AFAIK, the EffectComposers write/readBuffer should hold the texture that would get rendered to screen if no effect is set to `renderToScreen = true;`.

If there are any more informations needed in order to resolve this issue, please let me know.

Regards,
Michael

Using three.js r82

Comment: i'm not familiar with composers and without code or a jsfiddle even an expert is unlikely to be able to help you. But as a wild guess I think you may be having a timing problem e.g. a downstream operation is attempting to read data before an upstream operation has finished writing it.  This can be solved by outputting upstream texture to a mesh in a (hidden) scene with an orthographic camera and rendering to a buffer. Then on the next animation step read the buffer data into the downstream operation.  I am hazy on details but you can search related stack overflow posts.

Comment: Hey steve, I haven't included any code here because I wasn't sure which path to choose at the time I wrote this. However: I created a Forum post here (http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/27318-threejs-webglrendertargettexture-as-uniform/) where I explain the problem in a more detailed way. But I'll update my post on here later. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aaaaaaand we're done!

After testing around and finally, creating another issue on github, I was able to solve this issue.

I stuck with this for now, since it works like a absolute charm.

This is the code that I use to create my texture:

```
var firstOutput = document.getElementById("CanvasOne"); //Get the filled canvas;
var tmpTxt = new THREE.CanvasTexture(firstOutput); //Create the texture;

//Set both min- and magFilter to the correct filtering;
tmpTxt.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
tmpTxt.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
tmpTxt.generateMipmaps = false; //Set this to resolve the image dstortion;
```

Afterwards, I was able to use `tmpTxt` as a uniform.