# Three.js r84 - EffectComposer: Can't re-use WebGLRenderTarget.texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently trying to setup a technique described in an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271770/effectcomposer-access-the-image-created-by-the-composer/41429433#41429433) I've created.

The ShaderPass uses the texture within the `readBuffer` to fill the tDiffuse uniform.
You can see this at Line 49 [on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js).
I then modified the ShaderPass to contain another property, `this.exportBuffer`.

`this.exportBuffer` gets filled with the `readBuffer` used to render to in Line 61. The property gets filled after `renderer.render()` was called.

I then proceed to extract the `exportBuffer.texture` property from the last ShaderPass.
In my theory, the exported `exportBuffer.texure`should hold the image within the last `writeBuffer` which should be the image displayed on my first EffectComposer.

However: The texture within the `exportBuffer`appears to stay black no matter what I try.

If there's anymore information or code that I can provide in order to resolve this problem, please let me know.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it is due to the limitation that multiple webgl canvases cannot share the same context (see http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-techniques-and-performance).

I'd suggest you use the same renderer to run your two EffectComposers. From what I see, all you have to do is point the "map" of your "scndMat" to the right output texture before you start to render the 2nd EffectComposer.

Comment: Due to the fact that WebGLRenderTarget can be configured with a specific size, it seems reasonable to assume that differently sized WebGLRenderTarget instances can be used for different EffectComposers - e.g. one matching the specific size of your image and then another one for the final output on the screen. I don't think that it is necessary to directly manipulate the renderers size.. eventhough the EffectComposer might just be doing that behind the scences (I did not look at that code..)